# Manual indexed NACK of a batch doesn't work after a retryable exception has been triggered without encapsulation in a BatchListenerFailedException

Tags: spring-kafka

Manual indexed nack of a batch of records does not work after a retryable exception has been triggered without encapsulation in a BatchListenerFailedException.

This nack works correctly when

- there is no exception
- the exception to be retried is encapsulated in a BatchListenerFailedException
- the nack is done in a batch which does not follow a batch having been retried

The documentation is not clear on this subject. It seems that Spring is not aware of the seek to be performed in such cases, as the consumer has been paused.

Let's take the following portion as an example

```
    boolean fail = true;
    boolean nack = true;

    @KafkaListener(
            id = "my-id",
            topics = "my-topic",
            containerFactory = "my-factory" // batch listener with MANUAL or MANUAL_IMMEDIATE ack mode, default error handler
    )
    public void on(List<ConsumerRecord<String, MyPojo>> consumerRecords, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
        logger.error("CONSUMED {} records with the following keys {}",
                consumerRecords.size(),
                consumerRecords.stream().map(ConsumerRecord::key).toList()
        );

        if (fail && consumerRecords.size() > 2) {
            fail = false;
            logger.error("FIRE TRANSIENT EXCEPTION");
            throw new TransientException("transient"); // this exception is registered as a retriable exception. It can work if this exception is wrapped into a BatchListenerFailedException
        }
        if (nack && consumerRecords.size() > 2) {
            nack = false;

            logger.error("NACK AT INDEX 2 with offset {}", consumerRecords.get(2).offset());
            acknowledgment.nack(2, Duration.ofMillis(0));
        }
    }
```

In this scenario, suppose a previous batch reprocessed due to a transient exception. If we nack index 2, we should reprocess records starting from index 2 but this is not the case.
The next batch is processed and remaining records from the previous batch are lost.

If we say it differently

- Batch 1: transient exception is fired
- Batch 1 is reprocessed
- Batch 2 with 5 records: nack index 2 => last 2 records of the batch should be reprocessed but this is not the case

Isn't it something that should be fixed to avoid weird/unexpected results? If this can't be fixed, it should certainly fails with a clear exception? Is there something else to do or differently?

Hope that the description of the issue is clear.

Thanks a lot for any help/clarification.